# A partir de un select, llenar un input de tipo text

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

***Buenas noches!
Saludos!***
Alguien me puede ayudar y orientar un poco por favor, en cuanto llenar un input, desde un select en la misma vista solo utilizando el mouse. Utilizo ***laravel*** versión es 5.1.46.

Mi vista es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo del select funcional:

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
             <label for="tercero_id">Tercero*</label>
                         <select id="tercero_id"  class="form-control"  >
                                <option value="">Seleccione Tercero*</option>
                                <?php 
                                foreach($contra as $contras){
                                    if(empty($contras->business_name)){
                                        echo ' <option value="'.$contras->id.'">'.$contras->firts_name.' '.$contras->last_name.' '.$contras->apellido1.' '.$contras->apellido2.'</option>';
                                    }else{
                                        echo ' <option value="'.$contras->id.'">'.$contras->business_name.'</option>';
                                    
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                                        
                            </select>  
                        </div>

         <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label for="nit">Nit*</label>
            <input type="text" id="nit"  class="form-control" disabled>
        </div>
```

entonces el procedimiento que intento hacer es:

1. Al momento de yo seleccionar cualquier valor en el select me llene el input del nit, con la **identificación** de ese valor seleccionado.
2. la identificación está en la misma tabla en mysql, y se vería así; Cabe resaltar que es una simulación de la tabla para mostrar solo el dato que quiero llenar en el ***nit***  (identificación) ya que las tablas son muchas:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El funcionamiento que necesito en pocas palabras es:

Si yo selecciono ***Central de materiales*** en el select, el nit se me debe auto- cargar con  la identificación que en este caso seria ***1234568***

Comment: si hay trabajo hecho solo, resumí código y texto...

Comment: Si estas usando Jquery una opción rápida sin hacer peticiones extras es que a tus options coloques un id, por ejemplo *id="option1" * y a cada option colocas un atributo, ejemplo *data-nit="123" luego con un **onchange** accedes al atributo y listo

Comment: Buen día, estas utilizando livewire o AJAX?

Comment: Buenos días, josue entiendo lo del jquery,  pero cuando hago el foreach solo traigo los nombres no sabria como traer, identificacion en ese mismo foreach para que  se pinte en el otro input, al yo seleccionar en el select.

Comment: HeytalePazguato, Buenos dias, no no estoy utilizando ninguno de los dos. solo una instancia de la clase contra() que viene siendo la tabla de la base de datos, la cual recorro en un foreach para mostrar los valores en el select.

Comment: con este evento traigo el id de esa tabla pero no la identificación. como hago para cambiar los datos: $("#tercero_id").change(function(){
     // a la variable x le asigno el value del select con id="seleccionarCliente"
     var x = $('#tercero_id').val();
     // le asigno el valor de x al input con id="cdCliente"
     $("#nit").val(x);
   });

Answer (score 2):

Como te comentaron otros usuarios es agregar un atributo "data" a cada option, donde deberas de poner el campo identificador y con la función onchange actualizaras el valor de tu input nit.

```js
function selectNit(e) {
    var nit =  e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-nit")
    document.getElementById("nit").value = nit;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="selectNit(event)">
    <option disabled selected>Seleccione Tercero*</option>
    <option data-nit="1234568" value="1">Central de materiales</option>
    <option data-nit="235648" value="2">lito impresos tanos</option>
    <option data-nit="23568442" value="3">marfil impresos y papel</option>
    <option data-nit="2525252" value="4">moldutriplex</option>
</select>

<input id="nit" type="text" disabled>
```